# Mac OSX Proxy Issue

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac, proxy

So I want to use Tor and have downloaded it multiple times from this page: https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#downloads (which I believe was the bundle).

I have tried to totally uninstall it, which I believe I did (but don't know for sure), some people have recommended using a fresh directory which I don't know how to do. Also, the Tor website recommends the command: "sudo port uninstall tor", which I've tried multiple times and entered my password but nothing happens after that.

What I'm stuck at is at the point where it says "TorBrowser is an application downloaded from the internet. Are you sure you want to open it?" I click open and a regular Firefox page opens up and when I enter an .onion link or anything else, proxy errors pop up (and I've checked, the settings are correct using 127.0.0.1 and 9050 or 9150).

I found this great guide with pictures (https://ssd.eff.org/en/module/how-use-tor-mac-os-x) but I can never get to the point where it actually confirms I have access to Tor. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

If it makes a difference, I use also norton antivirus and the Mac firewall is up.

Comment: I don't so OSX so I can't help with most of this but `sudo port uninstall tor` is a red herring, unrelated to the Tor Browser app. It's related to the standalone tor daemon that can be installed through ports, it won't affect Tor Browser. At a guess it's the "anti"-virus, it's a common cause on other platforms.

Comment: @vre02f Try and disable Norton antivirus and the OS's firewall and see if you can access the internet via Tor.